# D3.js svg element traversal

Tags: d3.js

```
//build legend key
        var svgContainer = d3.select("#TMLegend").append("svg")
              .attr("width", 972)
              .attr("height", 30);
        var width = 35, height = 10, x = 0;

        for(var e =0; e < root.children.length; e++){           
           svgContainer
              .append("rect")
              .attr("x", 0)
              .attr("y", 10)
              .attr("width", width)
              .attr("height", height)
              .attr("transform", "translate("+(36*x++)+",0)")
              .style("fill", function(){
                return colorArr[root.children[e].name];
              })
              .attr("title", function(){
                return root.children[e].name;
              })

              .text(function(){
                return root.children[e].name;
              });  
        }
d3.selectAll("#TMLegend rect").on("mouseover",function () {
        var title = d3.select(this).text();
        $("#TMLegendPopUp").show().html("<h4>"+title+"</h4>");
          //Popoup position
         $(document).mousemove(function(e){
             var popLeft = e.pageX + 10;
             var popTop = e.pageY + -90;
             $("#TMLegendPopUp").css({"left":popLeft,"top":popTop});
             $("#TMLegendPopUp h4").css({"background": colorArr[title], "margin":0});
        });    
    });
```

The above code was my attempt at targeting a div with id of TMLegend  and trying to drill down to the svg:rect.attr('id') to get the content of the rect element id. Since then, i have eliminated placing an ID Attr() and am now targeting the text(). This code works when the rect nodes are hard coded, but not when i use D3 to generate them. Does anyone have a way for getting the text of the rect elements with D3 dynamically?

The hard-coded html looks like this:

```
        <div id="TMLegend">
       <svg width="972" height="30">
```

Agricultural Products
Precious Stones & Metals
Mineral Products
Construction Materials
Textiles
          
      
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is as expected as `d3.select` only selects the first matching element. You need to use `d3.selectAll` to select all of the rectangles in your legend, then use `d3.select(this)` to target each individual rect when they are moused-over. Based on what I think you are trying to accomplish, you want something like:

```
d3.selectAll("#TMLegend rect").on("mouseover",function () { 
  $("#TMLegendPopUp").show()
    .html("<h4 style='margin:0'>" + d3.select(this).attr("id") + "</h4>");

    //Popoup position
   $(document).mousemove(function(e){
       var popLeft = e.pageX + 10;
       var popTop = e.pageY + -90;
       $("#TMLegendPopUp").css({"left":popLeft,"top":popTop});
   }); 
});
```

Comment: That does not seem to work. I tried removing the 'rect' from the selectAll, and i get an array containing TMLegend as the id. This is expected. Is there anything wrong with the selectAll function that i have in my code as far as how i am querying the DOM? Thank you for the response though.

Comment: Do you have x and y positions for you rectangles? You don't show them here. If not, they would be on top of each other, and only the last one would get the mouseover event.

Comment: Thanks so much Andy, you are correct. I figured out what i was doing wrong in my code.

Comment: However, there is something troubling that i have observed within D3. When these rectangle nodes are hard coded, your above example works. But, when D3 dynamically generates them, the above code fails with no error. I will revise and show exactly how i am generating the rect nodes.